# PHPUnit: creating custom code coverage reporter / logger

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

To contextualise, in similar tools, [PHPMD](https://phpmd.org/) and [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer), one can specify a custom formatter for result output, eg:

PHPMD:

```
 vendor/bin/phpmd test \\my\\namespace\\renderers\\phpmd\\AdamFormat phpmd.xml
```

PHPCS:

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=phpcs.xml --report=./src/renderers/phpcs/AdamFormat.php
```

I'm looking to do the same thing for PHPUnit, but have thusfar drawn a blank (investigation, googling, searching here). Looking at the code of PHPUnit, it all seems a bit hard-codey to me:

[Code coverage handler](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php#L581):

```
if (isset($arguments['coverageClover'])) {
    $this->printer->write(
        "\nGenerating code coverage report in Clover XML format ..."
    );
    try {
        $writer = new CloverReport;
```

[Logging](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php#L360):

```
if (isset($arguments['testdoxHTMLFile'])) {
    $result->addListener(
        new HtmlResultPrinter(
```

I have not spotted anywhere in the [docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions) that suggest otherwise. Seems like an odd shortfall to me.

So two questions:

1. Am I reading things right? PHPUnit doesn't support this?
2. Presuming that's "yes: not supported", has anyone had any success with a tactic to circumventing this in a non [Heath Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) manner?

I realise that one can use the `--coverage-php` option to output the results as PHP variables for another process to then utilise to do [whatever], but that seems like an inside out approach to me, and falls into the Heath Robinson category.

Comment: I don't believe PHPUnit supports custom formatters out of the box. re:  Heath Robinson, I do run phpunit within exec calls of another php script, calling phpunit with json format, and store the buffered result in a string and use json_decode, then do stuff with it.

Comment: That's not a bad Heath Robinson approach. Cheers for the tip.

Comment: Phpunit is opensource. Fork it, hack it in, make a pull request if you like - you don't have to. Most likely there are interfaces / abstractions for logging already, so it should be straight forward.